# Question regarding positivity of integrals

Tags: integration

If we have a continuous function $ f $ defined on a real interval $[a,b]$ such that  $ f(x)\ge 0$ for all $ x \in [a,b] $ , then can I say that $\int^x_a f(t)dt\ge 0$?

Comment: Is there any condition stating the range of $x$ for the integral?

Comment: I assume you mean $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$?  Then yes.

Comment: yes that is what I meant. Thank you, is $\int^b_x f(x)\ge 0$ as well?

Comment: Let's clarify a few points of interpretation. By "all terms", you probably mean $f(t) \geq 0$ for all $t \in [a,x]$. And by $\int_a^x f(x)$, I suspect you mean $\int_a^x f(t)dt$ (the $dt$ doesn't really matter and is a matter of convention and taste. But using the same variable as a dummy variable and as a bound is a bit peculiar). Or perhaps you meant for the upper bound to be $b$, since you mentioned it elsewhere?

Comment: @user1961722 Yes.  $\int_x^b f(t)dt \ge 0$ as well.

Comment: thank you. By "all terms" I mean $ f(t)\ge 0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. And yes, I mean $\int^x_a f(t)dt$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(t) \ge 0$ for all $t \in [a,b]$, then the integral $\int_a^x f(t)dt \ge 0$ for $x \in [a,b]$.  Likewise $\int_x^b f(t)dt \ge 0$ for $x \in [a,b]$.  This is clear if you think of integration as finding the signed area under a curve.  The area can't be negative if the graph of $f(t)$ never goes below the $t$-axis.

This could also be proved more rigorously by showing that any Riemann sum $\sum_i^n f(t_i)\Delta t_i$ must be non-negative.

Comment: true; I didn't think about it in terms of the area. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if you will see this-- but is the converse true as well? Does $\int^x_a fdt \ge 0 \implies f(t) \ge 0$?

Comment: @user42 No. For an elementary example consider the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x\ne 2 \\ -1, & x=2\end{cases}$ on the domain $x\in [0,2]$.  Then $\int_0^x f(t)dt \ge 0$ for all $x\in [0,2]$, but $f(x) \not\ge 0$ for all $x\in [0,2]$.

Comment: Notice, I don't even really need for $f$ to be negative on a set of measure $0$.  This would work just as well for $g$ defined by $g(x) = \begin{cases} 10^{10}, & x\lt 0.5 \\ -1, & x\ge 0.5\end{cases}$ defined on $x\in [0,2]$. I wouldn't even need this to be a discontinuous function. Can you come up with a continuous function which fails this hypothesis over a compact domain?